# Помогите найти ошибку в решении задачи. (Java)

Tags: java

```
public static boolean booleanExpression(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d) {
    boolean k[] = new boolean[6];
    k[0] = a & b;
    k[1] = a & c;
    k[2] = a & d;
    k[3] = b & c;
    k[4] = b & d;
    k[5] = c & d;
    short counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i > 7; ++i){
        if(k[i]){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    if (counter == 1 ){
        return true;
    }
    else {
         return false;
    }

}
```

========================================================================
**Задание**: Реализуйте метод, возвращающий true, если среди четырех его аргументов ровно два истинны (любые). Во всех остальных случаях метод должен возвращать false.

Comment: В чем заключается ошибка нам предстоит догадаться? Зачем вам вообще k[]?

Comment: Про инициализацию циклов перечитайте главу. Ваш цикл ни разу не исполняется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Писал на коленке в блокноте, но поченму не так?

```
public static boolean booleanExpression(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d)
{
    int i=0; 
    if (a) i++;
    if (b) i++;
    if (c) i++;
    if (d) i++;
    return i == 2;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, отличное решение.

Answer (score 1):

`public static boolean booleanExpression(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d) { 
        return (a? 1: 0) + (b? 1: 0) + (c? 1: 0) + (d? 1: 0) == 2 
}`

P. s. Что это вообще за код? Это школа? Так не пишите больше

Comment: думаете вот так стоит писать? `( ( (a? 1: 0)+(b? 1: 0)+(c? 1: 0)+(d? 1: 0)) == 2)`?

Comment: Красивое решение!

Comment: Пожалуй, самое лучшее, что я сейчас вижу, будет так: return (a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 1 : 0) + (c ? 1 : 0) + (d ? 1 : 0) == 2; Есть еще лучше варианты?